# Regular Expressions in the Cucumber feature file parameters

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, selenium-ide, cucumber-jvm

Is there a way to write Regular Expressions in the Cucumber feature file parameters?

for example I would like to write something like:

When I click "Edit*"

[ then Edit* will match all strings with prefix Edit (for example: Edit_Button) ]

But when I will write:

When I click "Edit"

[only Edit will be matched.]

I want the step to allow both parameter options (Edit or Edit*)

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I'd advise to not 'click "edit"' because that is not user behavior. Uses will 'edit' and click edit in order to edit. But that could change to a swipe in the future. When I edit the information, the button text or actions can be contained within the step. It's vastly superior for maintenance of your tests in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done but not in the way you suggest. The "Edit*" in the example will be a `String` in your step definition. What you could do is write some logic that takes a string and converts that into the regex you want. Some examples [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html).